# Java bank account project issue

Tags: java, oop

So, I followed the online youtube tutorial for this, and it worked for the tutorial instructor, but not me... However, only because it wants a "getBalance" class in the source classes. If someone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to Java, and I do have some reading to catch up on in the book... So here's the program and its class setup:

### BankAccountDemo.java

```
package bankaccountdemo;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class BankAccountDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(12.00);

    BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount(account1);

    DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#.##0.00");

    System.out.print("The balance in account #1 is $" + dollar.format(account1.getBalance()));
    System.out.print("The balance in account #2 is $" + dollar.format(account2.getBalance()));
  }
}
```

### BankAccount.java

```
package bankaccountdemo;

public class BankAccount {

  private double balance;

  public BankAccount() {
    balance = 0.0;
  }

  public BankAccount(BankAccount obj) {
    balance = obj.balance;
  }

  public BankAccount(double startBalance) {
    balance = startBalance;
  }
}
```

I am aware that this is a pretty simple fix, but as I said.. I have some reading to catch up on. I understood the lottery problem better than this very simple bug.

Comment: If you don't understand methods, you've skipped over a few sections of the official Java tutorial.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 2):

> it wants a "getBalance" class in the source classes.

It doesn't want a class it wants a method that is called on your bankaccount object.

```
account1.getBalance()
```

So you need to create a method in your BankAccount class.

```
public double getBalance(){
  return balance;
}
```

This function is called a getter function. In OOP languages an object's properties are usually created as private and can be modified/set and read/get using this setter and getter functions.

so you can create another function like

```
public void setBalance(double balance){
  this.balance = balance;
}
```

and then you can use

```
account1.setBalance(10.0);
```

to set the amount to 10.0

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you need a `getBalance()` method in `BankAccount`:

```
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
```

Comment: package bankaccountdemo;

public class BankAccount {

    private double balance;

    public BankAccount() {
        balance = 0.0;
    }

    public BankAccount(BankAccount obj) {
        balance = obj.balance;
    }

    public BankAccount(double startBalance) {
        balance = startBalance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
         return balance;
    }
}

Comment: I added it in, and I still get errors and it fails to work.

Comment: @Banba That's a completely useless problem description. There could be a million reason why it doesn't work. Why don't you tell me what error(s) you're getting?

Comment: The problem is just about solved. The error had something to mostly do with the decimal format output. "DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#.##");"

Comment: Problem solved, thanks to everyone on here. I changed the decimal output to "#.00" and it works great.